# How to change version information of *.a files after compilation

Tags: linux, unix, makefile

I would like to know what is the way (if it is possible at all), to change the version information of a *.a files in Unix after the compilation.
I know how to do it for Dll files in windows - but have no idea how to manage with it in Unix.

Thank you all!

Comment: What "version information" are you talking about? Which tool would show it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static libraries are just archives of .o files - they don't embed version themselves unless your code somehow publishes a symbol that holds version information.

Like:

```
int libFoo_version = 0x01000000;
```

Or you could use

```
char* libFoo_version = "1.0";
```

and afterwards use something like the `strings libFoo.a | grep libFoo_version` command in combination with `sed` to alter the version information.

Yet another option is to embed an empty file in the archive which name contains the version information. YMMV

Comment: Thanks,
but how will the end users know that this contains the version info? Do I have to mention it explicitely?
Isn't there a generic way?

Comment: There is no generic way. You may want to provide an API to retrieve the version information.

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I remember, ranlib has been integrated into ar which makes me think it doesn't offer a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Static libraries don't have version information per se.

Answer (score 0):

If the version is part of the source code (for example, a string constant), then you can simply use `sed` to change it if the new version has the same length as the old one.

Comment: Hi,
I've been told that ranlib may do this work.
Is it correct?
Thanks!

Comment: ranlib just creates an index of the symbols in the library (equivalent to `ar -s`).